# Usage of exceptionExpression in Spring Retry

Tags: spring, spring-retry

According to documentation, I can use something like this in `exceptionExpression`: `@Retryable(exceptionExpression="message.contains('this can be retried')")`

But I want to get response body and check message inside it (from `RestClientResponseException`), something similar to this: `exceptionExpression = "getResponseBodyAsString().contains('important message')"`

I tried like that but it doesn't work. So, is it possible to do something similar and check info from responseBody?

---

Edit: Adding whole `@Retryable` annotation parameters with Gary Russell's suggestion:

`@Retryable(value = HttpClientErrorException.class, exceptionExpression = "#{#root instanceof T(org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException) AND responseBodyAsString.contains('important message')}")`

I'm using actual `RestClientResponseException` subclass that I'm catching but is still not triggering retry.

Answer (score 3):

I've implemented the following approach, which in my opinion is much more convenient.

```
@Retryable(value = WebClientException.class,
        exceptionExpression = RetryCheckerService.EXPRESSION,
        maxAttempts = 5,
        backoff = @Backoff(delay = 500))
public List<ResultDto> getSomeResource () {}
```

Here the RetryCheckerService encapsulates all needed logic.

```
@Service
public class RetryCheckerService {
    public static final String EXPRESSION = "@retryCheckerService.shouldRetry(#root)";


public boolean shouldRetry(WebClientException ex) {
    if (ex instanceof WebClientResponseException responseException) {
        return responseException.getStatusCode().is5xxServerError()
                || responseException.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    if (ex instanceof WebClientRequestException requestException) {
        String message = requestException.getMessage();
        if (message == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return message.contains("HttpConnectionOverHTTP");
    }

    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the current release, the expression incorrectly requires static template markers; they will not be needed in 1.3.

```
@Retryable(exceptionExpression = "#{responseBodyAsString.contains('foo')}")
```

However, you can't use this expression if there are `include` or `exclude` properties so the expression should check the type:

```
@Retryable(exceptionExpression =
        "#{#root instanceof T(org.springframework.web.client.RestClientResponseException) "
        + "AND responseBodyAsString.contains('foo')}")
```

**EDIT**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableRetry
public class So61488237Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So61488237Application.class, args).close();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(Foo foo) {
        return args -> {
            try {
                foo.test(1, "foo.");
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
            }
        };
    }

}

@Component
class Foo {

    @Retryable(exceptionExpression =
            "#{#root instanceof T(org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException) "
            + "AND responseBodyAsString.contains('foo')}")
    public void test(int val, String str) {
        System.out.println(val + ":" + str);
        throw new RestClientResponseException("foo", 500, "bar", new HttpHeaders(), "foo".getBytes(),
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }

 }
```

```
1:foo.
1:foo.
1:foo.
```

Comment: I edited question with your changes added to my code but still is not retrying. Maybe I'm missing something else? PS: I'm using version: '1.2.5.RELEASE'

Comment: You are looking for the wrong type `HttpClientErrorException` instead of `RestClientException`; I added my full test app.
Also, `value` is a synonym for `include` - the expression can't be used with `include()` and `exclude()`.